# Photoshop/Javascript - EPS to Tiff file conversion and removing duplicates

Tags: javascript, photoshop, tiff, eps, photoshop-script

Hey all so I have this script that converts EPS files to Tiffs in Photoshop.

At present it allows you to pick a folder of files to be converted and creates a new folder in that for the Tiff files. I had tried creating the Tiffs in the same folder without creating an extra folder but this seemed to mess with the original EPS file. The conversion was happening fine but it was taking the data out of the EPS and saving it like a blank file. Since I put the new converted Tiff files in a folder it is creating a copy of the original EPS in there too which I don't need.

Basically I need to convert all the EPS files in a folder to Tiffs but do not want to mess with the original EPS and do not want an additional copies of the file.

The script I have at present is as follows:

```
#include "~/AppData/Local/wbmUtils/lib/underscore.js";

//-------------- declare measurement in pixels and declare vars for HxW --------------\\
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
var height =0;
var width = 0;

//-------------- select input and output folders --------------\\
alert("Choose a folder of EPS's");
var inPath  = Folder.selectDialog();
var outPath  = inPath+'/Tiffs';
$.writeln(inPath);
$.writeln(outPath);

//-------------- get full image list from input folder --------------\\
var inputs = getImageList (inPath);
function getImageList (dirPath) 
{
    var contents = dirPath.getFiles();
    var imageList=[];
    _.each(contents, function(item)
    {
        imageList.push(item.toString());
    })
    return imageList;
}

//-------------- create new folder for files --------------\\
$.writeln(inputs);
var imageFolderName = outPath;
var imageFolder = Folder(imageFolderName);
if(!imageFolder.exists) imageFolder.create();
_.each(inputs, function(input)
{
    $.writeln("height: " + height + "  width: " + width);
    var imgWithExt =  _.last(input.split('/'))
    doPreviews(input,  imageFolderName +'/' + imgWithExt);  
    var of = new File(input); 
    of.copy (imageFolderName +'/' + imgWithExt.split('.')[0] + '.eps');
})

//-------------- main conversion function --------------\\
function doPreviews(input, output)
{
    var idOpn = charIDToTypeID("Opn ");
    var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    desc4.putPath(idnull, new File(input));
    var idAs = charIDToTypeID("As  ");
    var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idRslt = charIDToTypeID("Rslt");
    var idRsl = charIDToTypeID("#Rsl");
    desc5.putUnitDouble(idRslt, idRsl, 300.000000);
    var idAntA = charIDToTypeID("AntA");
    desc5.putBoolean(idAntA, true);
    var idEPSG = charIDToTypeID("EPSG");
    desc4.putObject(idAs, idEPSG, desc5);
    executeAction(idOpn, desc4, DialogModes.NO);

    var idMk = charIDToTypeID("Mk  ");
    var desc7 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    var idDcmn = charIDToTypeID("Dcmn");
    ref1.putClass(idDcmn);
    desc7.putReference(idnull, ref1);
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID("Usng");
    var ref2 = new ActionReference();
    var idHstS = charIDToTypeID("HstS");
    var idCrnH = charIDToTypeID("CrnH");
    ref2.putProperty(idHstS, idCrnH);
    desc7.putReference(idUsng, ref2);
    executeAction(idMk, desc7, DialogModes.NO);

    height = app.activeDocument.height;
    width = app.activeDocument.width;

    if (height > width) 
    {
        $.writeln("IS HIGHER THAN WIDE");
        var idImgS = charIDToTypeID("ImgS");
        var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idHght = charIDToTypeID("Hght");
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
        desc8.putUnitDouble(idHght, idPxl, 6500.000000);
        var idscaleStyles = stringIDToTypeID("scaleStyles");
        desc8.putBoolean(idscaleStyles, true);
        var idCnsP = charIDToTypeID("CnsP");
        desc8.putBoolean(idCnsP, true);
        var idIntr = charIDToTypeID("Intr");
        var idIntp = charIDToTypeID("Intp");
        var idautomaticInterpolation = stringIDToTypeID("automaticInterpolation");
        desc8.putEnumerated(idIntr, idIntp, idautomaticInterpolation);
        executeAction(idImgS, desc8, DialogModes.NO);
    } else {
        $.writeln("IS WIDER THAN HIGH");
        var idImgS = charIDToTypeID("ImgS");
        var desc32 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idWdth = charIDToTypeID("Wdth");
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
        desc32.putUnitDouble(idWdth, idPxl, 6500.000000);
        var idscaleStyles = stringIDToTypeID("scaleStyles");
        desc32.putBoolean(idscaleStyles, true);
        var idCnsP = charIDToTypeID("CnsP");
        desc32.putBoolean(idCnsP, true);
        var idIntr = charIDToTypeID("Intr");
        var idIntp = charIDToTypeID("Intp");
        var idautomaticInterpolation = stringIDToTypeID("automaticInterpolation");
        desc32.putEnumerated(idIntr, idIntp, idautomaticInterpolation);
        executeAction(idImgS, desc32, DialogModes.NO);
    }

    var idMk = charIDToTypeID("Mk  ");
    var desc20 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref4 = new ActionReference();
    var idDcmn = charIDToTypeID("Dcmn");
    ref4.putClass(idDcmn);
    desc20.putReference(idnull, ref4);
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID("Usng");
    var ref5 = new ActionReference();
    var idHstS = charIDToTypeID("HstS");
    var idCrnH = charIDToTypeID("CrnH");
    ref5.putProperty(idHstS, idCrnH);
    desc20.putReference(idUsng, ref5);
    executeAction(idMk, desc20, DialogModes.NO);

    var idCls = charIDToType("Cls ");
    executeAction(idCls, desc20, DialogModes.NO);

    //-------------- tiff options --------------\\
    tiffSaveOptions = new TiffSaveOptions();
    tiffSaveOptions.byteOrder = ByteOrder.MACOS;
    tiffSaveOptions.layers = false;
    tiffSaveOptions.transparency = true;
    tiffSaveOptions.alphaChannels = true;
    tiffSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = false;
    tiffSaveOptions.imageCompression = TIFFEncoding.TIFFLZW;
    tiffSaveOptions.saveImagePyramid = false; 

    app.activeDocument.saveAs(File(output.split('.')[0]+'.tiff'), tiffSaveOptions, true);
    app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}

//-------------- success message --------------\\
alert("ALL DONE!")
```

Comment: to get the files into the original folder in the way that removes the data from the original eps just remove +'/Tiffs' from line 11 so it just says     var outPath  = inPath;

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do this with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

So, at the command-line in your Terminal:

```
mkdir TIFFs                             # Make the output directory called "TIFFs"
mogrify -format tif -path TIFFs *.eps   # Convert all EPS to TIFFs/*.tif
```